# C# serial port outgoing traffic sniffing

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've been looking around quite alot for a way to sniff outgoing traffic on a serial port.
The reason I want to do that is to be able to sniff and decipher message Im sending from another app I have.

There are apps that allow sniffing on a serial port without blocking it from other apps (I usually use free serial port monitor).

Is there a way to do that with C#? 
Thanks

Comment: No, it requires a filter driver.  Writing a driver in C# is not possible.  This is buy, not build, you need to go shopping.

Comment: You ask if you could develope a port sniffer in C# or do you ask for a port sniffer suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean...? There are apps that do that.

Comment: @AshChlor And those are not written in C#.

Comment: I know that there are apps that do that. What I'm looking for is a way to get that data into another app (my own app).

Comment: @Gnqz, yes I figured C# is not quite equipped for that.. Is there another way maybe? using some API or something of that sort?

Comment: What you could do is use a program, which allows you to output ougoing data into a file and use the filestream as an input.

Comment: @Gnqz, thats actually a great idea :) I'll try that one out.. thanks alot!